# How to define a function without using .values() to get values from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
def getValues(myDict):
  return list(myDict.items())[0][1] # <-- my code returns only 1 value, I need all values

courses = {'CPS141':60, 'CSS210':30, 'CPS161':20}
print(getValues(courses))
```

## expected output: [60,30,20]

Comment: `list(myDict.values())`

Comment: Why don't you want to use `.values()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
[value for key, value in myDict.items()]
```